# Why does Cap Production Deploy fire, but not update my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean

Using Capistrano to push a Ruby on Rails application hosted on a DigitalOcean server. A previous dev team built the deployment configuration, I'm trying to push an update as stored on the GitHub repo.

The 'cap production deploy' command goes through, but nothing on the server changes. The trace on the command line is a mile long, I can post it if it will help.

Here's my deploy.rb file:

```
require 'soprano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'whenever/capistrano'
require 'leipreachan/capistrano2'

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => '/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH'
}


set :web_server, :nginx
set :keep_releases, 3

set :repository, 'git@github.com:mitigation/mpm.git'

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_exclude, %w(.git .idea .yardoc tmp log .DS_Store doc/* public/uploads.tar db/*.sql vendor/cache)
set :copy_cache, true

set :bundle_without, [:development, :test]
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --binstubs'

set :user, 'deploy'

before 'deploy:setup', :db
after 'deploy:create_symlink', 'utils:version'
after 'deploy:update_code', 'db:symlink'

#For troubleshooting only
namespace :deploy do
  task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    #on_rollback { run "rm -rf #{release_path}; true" }
    strategy.deploy!
    finalize_update
  end
end
```

EDIT 8/9/2016:
Here's the tail end of the command firing. It doesn't look like it threw an error, but nothing on the server changes.

```
2016-07-19 14:11:49 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /var/www/apps/mpm/current &&  ln -s /var/www/apps/mpm/releases/20160719180333 /var/www/apps/mpm/current"
    servers: ["104.131.68.111"]
    [104.131.68.111] executing command
    command finished in 99ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:create_symlink'
  * 2016-07-19 14:11:49 executing `utils:version'
  * executing "cd /var/www/apps/mpm/releases/20160719180333 && echo r1 > APP_VERSION"
    servers: ["104.131.68.111"]
    [104.131.68.111] executing command
    command finished in 94ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * 2016-07-19 14:11:49 executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "sudo service mpm restart"
    servers: ["104.131.68.111"]
    [104.131.68.111] executing command
 ** [out :: 104.131.68.111] mpm stop/waiting
 ** [out :: 104.131.68.111] mpm start/running, process 21131
    command finished in 214ms
```

Comment: Try manually restarting nginx or whatever web server you are using

Comment: If Capistrano encounters any error on the server, it should appear fairly near the bottom of the deploy output, and it would intentionally rollback the deployment so "no change" is expected behavior.  Scroll up the command output until you find what either looks like the start of a Ruby stack trace, or some meaningful shell error output.